# Need Excel Formulas to form keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I have this in A1:

"Dell Inspiron 15R i3531-1200BK 15.6" Notebook Computer with Windows 8.1 with Bing (Black)"

1. I want to cut out "Dell" as the first word in A2:

"Inspiron 15R i3531-1200BK 15.6" Notebook Computer with Windows 8.1 with Bing (Black)"

2. in A3 I might want to remove unnecessary words such as "with" and change the apostrophe(") to "inch" and remove the brackets () from (Black):

"Dell Inspiron 15R i3531-1200BK 15.6 inch Notebook Computer Windows 8.1 Bing Black"

Or if I wish to remove " altogether and remove the first word witihn that formula:

"Inspiron 15R i3531-1200BK 15.6 Notebook Computer Windows 8.1 Bing Black"

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You're more likely to get a good answer if you can ask a good question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297394/excel-parsing-and-converting-text for the `SUBSTITUTE` formula and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917686/excel-splitting-names-and-words/19917976#19917976 for using the `FIND` and `MID` formulas.

Comment: It is clear that you want string manipulation. But not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters have a point: your question is difficult to understand...

Nevertheless, I would go about what I think your task is, as follows:
- I would use each cell going right (A2, A3, A4, A5, etc...) as a single editing/cleaning rule only
- I would start with rules that pertain to the outer extremities of the line using the formulas LEFT() and RIGHT()
- Once those parts are "cleaned" as needed I would look at using FIND, MID, SUBSTITUTE as suggested in successive rules that clean your string as you want

I hope that helps.